# Installing Moog stabilizer / sway bar links on 2002 Ford Focus

Tags: suspension, focus, torque, grease, fastener

I am installing both front sway bar links on my 2002 Ford Focus SE wagon. I ordered a pair of "[MOOG K80066 Stabilizer Bar Link Kits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000C5449G)". They did not come with any instructions, and I am totally new to working on cars, so I had a couple of questions about installing them properly:

1) They have attachments for a grease gun. Do I need to grease them out of the box, or do they come pre-greased? How do I know when they need new grease? Also, what type of grease should I use in them, and how much?

2) I installed the first one, and decided to tighten the nuts attaching the ends of the stabilizer link really hard. Thinking about it afterwards, I realized that maybe there was a specific torque they were supposed to be tightened to, and that I might have seriously over tightened them.  How tight am I supposed to fasten the nuts? Is it possible that I did permanent damage to the bushings by overtightening them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely you tightened them to the point of causing  some damage. The paperwork that comes with the parts should have a reference to torque specs. An on line reference I found gives a value of 37ftlbs. As far as grease I use the chassis grease from the auto parts store. I generally give them a shot of grease prior to installation. I do this mostly to verify I will be able to grease it later. Two or three pumps is usually enough. You want to see the rubber boot swell but not so much that the grease pours out. This is done at every oil change.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have a grease gun. Would it be ok for me to drive on them ungreased just to the hardware store to buy one? Or would even a short drive like that damage them without lubrication?

Comment: The norm is for them to be prelubed  from the factory so you will be fine. If you plan on doing your own maintenance a grease gun is an inexpensive tool.